# Adjusting Y axis values bar graph

Tags: data-visualization, visualization, stata

I have the following Stata code which produces the graph below. However, I am trying to adjust/sort the values on the Y axis, which refers to workers in different income groups, to follow the same order as the dataset. Rather than the current order where those making <= 1.5 thousand dollars per month are arranged as the 5th rather than first income group.

```
number_of_workers   income_bracket
24806                <= 1.5
31346                 1.5-2.9
648409                   3
389266                3.01-4.9
351963                  5-9.9
271360                  >= 10
```

The income bracket variable is string and I tried to convert it as follows:

```
gen income_bracket_numeric = real(income_bracket)
```

However, Stata treats the converted values as missing (.), except for 3 which is numeric. Is there a way to deal with income bracket ranges by making it numeric, without altering the original data?

```
preserve
keep if nationality=="nationals"
keep if period=="Q1_2020" | period=="Q4_2020" 
graph hbar (mean)  number_of_workers, over(income_bracket) over(quarter)
restore
```

[image]

I incorporated Nick's advice, and my code looks as follows:

```
input number_of_workers_q1 str8 income_bracket_q1
24806 "<= 1.5"
31346 "1.5-2.9"
648409 "3"
389266 "3.01-4.9"
351963 "5-9.9"
271360 ">= 10"
end 


input number_of_workers_q4 str8 income_bracket_q4
25073 "<= 1.5"
29628 "1.5-2.9"
596767 "3"
442429 "3.01-4.9"
381794 "5-9.9"
273880 ">= 10"
end 

gen order = _n 
labmask order, values(income_bracket_q1)
graph hbar (asis) number_of_workers_q1 number_of_workers_q4, over(order)

label define order 1 "{&le} 1.5" 6 "{&ge} 10", modify 
graph hbar (asis) number_of_workers_q1 number_of_workers_q4, over(order)
```

And the graph works well except for that Y axis which looks as below:
[image]

Comment: So, `income_bracket` is a string variable and its distinct values are being sorted alphanumerically. `<` and `>` sort after the numeric characters `1 2 3 4 5`. You need a numeric variable version of your string variable. Show a reproducible data example and I will show how to do that.

Comment: Detail: Stata is so spelled. https://www.statalist.org/forums/help#spelling

Comment: Check the updated post and data example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that your question is about tweaking the categorical axis. With `graph bar`, `graph hbar` and `graph dot` the magnitude axis is always considered to be the *y* axis, regardless of whether it is vertical or horizontal. This is done so you can change the orientation between horizontal and vertical without being obliged to change all the `y` options and all the `x` options.

Here is one way to do it using `labmask` from the *Stata Journal*.

```
clear 
input number_of_workers str8 income_bracket
24806 "<= 1.5"
31346 "1.5-2.9"
648409 "3"
389266 "3.01-4.9"
351963 "5-9.9"
271360 ">= 10"
end 

gen order = _n 
labmask order, values(income_bracket)
graph hbar (asis) number_of_workers, over(order)

label define order 1 "{&le} 1.5" 6 "{&ge} 10", modify 
graph hbar (asis) number_of_workers, over(order)
```

You can do it without `labmask` if you define value labels in the right order and then use `encode`.

As above, you can improve on crude double symbols `<=` and `>=`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on using labmask (), extremely useful! I have updated my post as I still have one issue.

Comment: Use `if` to select observations or use `clear` to remove existing data (so long as you have `save`d it first).